# Boxplot time series monthly and weekly

Tags: pandas, time-series, boxplot

I have a pandas time series with the index containing dates with several years:

```
                        Sales
Order Date  
2019-01-01 03:07:00     11.99
2019-01-01 03:40:00     11.95
2019-01-01 04:56:00     150.00
2019-01-01 05:53:00     2.99
2019-01-01 06:03:00     23.90
...                     ...
2020-01-01 04:13:00     2.99
2020-01-01 04:21:00     11.95
2020-01-01 04:54:00     99.99
2020-01-01 05:13:00     99.99
2020-01-01 05:13:00     14.95
```

I am trying to make a boxplot with the total sales performed monthly and weekly for a specific year. So far I have tried to group the data using

```
weeks = [g.reset_index()
         for n, g in sales_dataframe.groupby(Grouper(freq='W'))]
months = [g.reset_index()
          for n, g in sales_dataframe.groupby(Grouper(freq='M'))]
```

How could I get the boxplots, for example, the year 2019 with the average sales monthly and weekly?

Comment: boxplot with total sales? Do you mean boxplot with mean sales? Or do you mean bar plot with total sales?

Comment: @QuangHoang with the average

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using Seaborn

```
sns.boxplot(x=sales_dataframe.index.month, y=sales_dataframe.Sales)
```